# How can I generate a plot of the partitions in Isolation Forests

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cart, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I have seen this plot is used to indicated how anomalies are isolated via partitioning in Isolation Forests. Is there a library to automatically plot this from a dataset? The plot I want to generate is in the image: [image]

Comment: This seems unlikely to be directly included in a library because it relies on having exactly two independent variables.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to make such a plot, using the [`decision_path`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeRegressor.decision_path) method of the underlying `ExtraTreeRegressor`s and some of the [tree structure](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#tree-structure) attributes.  The actual plotting of line segments that end at others might be the hardest part for me.

Answer (score 0):

That's a custom generated plot which explores the splits generated for a single node in a given tree, which is typically not what plotting methods do for decision trees. The authors do not provide any such functionality in the code for their paper either. That being said, if you use the implementation in scikit-learn, it uses the same tree format as for their other methods, so if you find some external library generating similar plots for e.g. random forests, you can use it for isolation forest too.